# React Popover 3rd-Party Out-Of-Window-View Problem

Tags: reactjs, window, popover, bounds, react-state

I'm looking for some accommodating a large 3rd-party software for a 1st-party concern.

I have a [Popover](https://material-ui.com/components/popover/), 
 
With 3rd-party GUI that is along the window's right-side, 
 
That throws `Warning: findDOMNode is deprecated in StrictMode.` 
I'd fix it if I could.

Normally, the Popover opening accommodates the window-view, 
 
But this Popover extends past the right-side. 
 
But-the-but, when I resize the window then the Popover fits itself back inside. 
 
What is going on here?

Because, I can't figure out how to: [`window.location.reload()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Location/reload) or [`id.hide().show()`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6242976/javascript-hide-show-element) without wiping the [`React.Function.Component`](https://reactjs.org/docs/components-and-props.html). 
 
[Which the Popover needs because I've been told](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62009609/react-class-how-to-anchorel-popover) that [`React.Class.Component`](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html) doesn't work with [React-Hooks](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html).

Again - what is going on here? So I can fix it.

Comment: my guts feeling is that you need give some time. for UI to reflect, don't know if this helps, https://kentcdodds.com/blog/useeffect-vs-uselayouteffect

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I think I know what's going on now.

The 3rd-party's React component isn't loaded yet until the Functional Popover Component presents it. This causes the `findDOMNode` warning to trigger because this component isn't hydrated on-the-reference yet and because the Popover is a Functional Component which does not work with `findDomNode`.

But, the real reason the React component falls-outside-the-window seems caused by placement before React hydration. And as I understand it, the 3rd-party component is server-side rendered which is why it has to be hydrated by them.

Thanks everyone for looking at this.